# During execution, how can a java program tell how much memory it is using?

Tags: java, memory, runtime

During execution, how can a java program tell how much memory it is using?

I don't care how efficient it is!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

VonC's answer is an interactive solution - if you want to know programatically, you can use [Runtime.totalMemory()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#totalMemory()) to find out the total amount used by the JVM, and [Runtime.freeMemory()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#freeMemory()) to find out how much of that is still available (i.e. it's allocated *to* the JVM, but not allocated *within* the JVM - new objects can use this memory).

These are instance methods - use [Runtime.getRuntime()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#getRuntime()) to first get the singleton instance.

Comment: You are correct (my initial reaction was to monitor from the outside), +1 to you ;)

Comment: Jon Skeet, hello, can you please tell me how to do the same for C#? in java I would subtract free from total, right? And in C# I only found PrivateMemorySize64 in the Process class, but I assume that only gives total memory, right?

Comment: @paulpaul1076: It would be better to ask a new question for that.

Comment: @JonSkeet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870969/how-can-i-tell-how-much-memory-my-application-is-using-in-c

Comment: @JonSkeet looks like the closed it as duplicate already, sorry

Answer (score 4):

If you are have a java1.6 somewhere and your program is running in java 1.4.2, 1.5 or 1.6, you can launch a [visualVM session](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/), connect to your application, and follow the memory (and much more)

[image: image of monitoring application with Visual VM]

(The images are not displayed at the moment, so please refers to [Monitoring an application](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/monitor_tab.html) for an illustration.)

Answer (score 4):

This won't be exact, but for a rough estimate, just subtract `Runtime.getRuntime.freeMemory()` from `Runtime.getRuntime.totalMemory()`.
Do that at the beginning of the program to get an idea of the `JVM's` overhead memory usage and at intervals latter on in the execution.

Answer (score -1):

java.lang.Runtime.totalMemory() will give you the required info: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

Comment: A prime example of why link-only answers are bad. I suggest you delete it altogether as the other answers provide all the necessary information.

Comment: @leonheess : If you observe carefully, my answer was not a link-only answer. I gave the answer and provided the link for extra information. Please take a look again!

Comment: I downvoted because your answer contains no explanation other than a dead link. Normally I'd encourage you to add an explanation but the other answers already cover that need.