# Java: how much memory is allocated to this process?

Tags: java, memory, junit

I've written a unit test which is very demanding on memory.  It requires the `-Xmx2048m` parameter, otherwise get a `OutOfMemoryException`.

Is there a way to check, from within the test, how much memory is allocated? It would be useful to write a test such as `TestsHaveEnoughMemory`, and fail it with an explanatory error message that tells the user a memory parameter is required.

Comment: possible duplicate of [During execution, how can a java program tell how much memory it is using?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239202/during-execution-how-can-a-java-program-tell-how-much-memory-it-is-using)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Runtime class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) to do that.

Try this;

```
long total_memory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();    // Total available now
long free_memory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();      // Free memory now
long max_memory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();        // Max available ever
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Runtime's [maxMemory()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#maxMemory%28%29) method to get how much heap is allocated to the process. Helpful link also [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/05/getting-jvm-heap-size-used-memory-total-memory-using-java-runtime.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the memory actually used via JMX API same as you see in jconsole

like this 
`ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed();`

you can get the Max like this
`ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage().getMax();`

Answer (score 0):

Try MemoryMXBean @ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html