# How much memory is my program using Java

Tags: java, memory, time, artificial-intelligence

I am made a program which uses A* search algorithm to solve 8 game puzzle.
I was interested in seeing how much memory is being used by my program from start to finish.

So far i have done

In the beginning of the program

```
static double totalMem = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/(1024*1024);
static double memoryMax = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/(1024*1024);
```

and at the end of the program

```
        timeTaken-=System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("\n\n-------Total Time Taken = "+Math.abs(timeTaken)+
                " millisec ------\n ");

        System.out.println("-------Maximum Memory  = "+memoryMax+" MB------\n ");

        System.out.println("-------Total Memory = "+totalMem
                +" MB------\n ");

        currMem = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/(1024*1024);

        System.out.println("-------Free Memory  = "+currMem+" MB------\n ");

        double memUsed = (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory())/(1024*1024)-currMem;

        System.out.println("-------Total Used = "+memUsed
                +" MB------\n ");
```

This doesn't seems to be right. When i test with different sets of data. Any sugessitions

Comment: "This doesn't seems to be right." Why?

Comment: Whats the problem with the above code?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPerformance/article.html

Comment: It seems right until you exceed the total memory JVM, then if program is huge it seems to use the max memory available. The only thing i could think is a if statement

Comment: Write that _in the question_, not in the comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [During execution, how can a java program tell how much memory it is using?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239202/during-execution-how-can-a-java-program-tell-how-much-memory-it-is-using)

Answer (score 6):

It would be better to use profiler or similar software for this purpose. You can start with jvisualvm which is included in JDK or JProfiler.

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks related to the thread-local allocation buffer.
The objects might be getting created on TLAB.
Read this: https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/the_real_thing
So everytime you run the program, it will show similar values.
Run the program by switching off this feature, pass below in VM arguments:-

```
-XX:-UseTLAB
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "Java Mission Control" (newer version of JVisualVM), that allows you to make snapshots of your memory. Add this parameters at startup of your programm:

```
-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures
-XX:+FlightRecorder
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Its in the "bin" folder of your JDK 7 too, called: "jmc.exe"

Answer (score 0):

Runtime works correctly. You could take the difference before executing the logic and after to see how much memory used. A quick sample

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MemoryTest {

    private static final int KB = 1024;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long initialMemory = getUsedMemory();
        List<String> dummy = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<10000; i++){
            dummy.add("Dummy " + i);
        }
        System.out.println("Total used by program = " + (getUsedMemory() - initialMemory) + " KB");
    }

    private static long getUsedMemory() {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        return (runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) / KB;
    }
}
```

Comment: It work fine until you exceed the totalMemory. In your case it wont exceed the totalMemory. But once it exceed totalMemory it will use the maxMemory and it if exceeds that then it's on a  limbo..